# HttpGet, HttpClient, HttpResponse, HttpEntity, EntityUtils deprectated

Tags: java, android, apache-httpclient-4.x, apache-httpcomponents

i'm using android studio API 23 and i have these warnings
[image: deprecated warning]

Here's my code

```
@Override
    protected Boolean doInBackground(String... urls) {
        String strNama[], strDeskripsi[], strFoto[], strMarker[], strLng[], strLat[];

        try {
            HttpGet httppost = new HttpGet(urls[0]);
            HttpClient httpclient = new DefaultHttpClient();
            HttpResponse response = httpclient.execute(httppost);
            int status = response.getStatusLine().getStatusCode();
            if (status == 200) {
                HttpEntity entity = response.getEntity();
                String data = EntityUtils.toString(entity);
                JSONObject jsono = new JSONObject(data);
                JSONArray konten = jsono.getJSONArray("konten");
                strNama = new String[konten.length()];
                strDeskripsi = new String[konten.length()];
                strFoto = new String[konten.length()];
                strMarker = new String[konten.length()];
                strLat = new String[konten.length()];
                strLng = new String[konten.length()];
                for (int i = 0; i < konten.length(); i++) {
                    JSONObject object = konten.getJSONObject(i);
                    strNama[i] = object.getString("nama");
                    strDeskripsi[i] = object.getString("deskripsi");
                    strFoto[i] = object.getString("foto");
                    strMarker[i] = object.getString("marker");
                    strLat[i] = object.getString("lat");
                    strLng[i] = object.getString("lng");
                    Actors actor = new Actors();
                    actor.setName(strNama[i]);
                    actor.setDescription(strDeskripsi[i]);
                    actor.setImage(strFoto[i]);
                    actor.setMarker(strMarker[i]);
                    actor.setLat(strLat[i]);
                    actor.setLng(strLng[i]);
                    actorsList.add(actor);
                }
                return true;
            }

        } catch (ParseException e1) {
            e1.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (JSONException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return false;
    }
```

And here's in module

```
android {
    compileSdkVersion 23
    buildToolsVersion "23.0.2"
    useLibrary 'org.apache.http.legacy'
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.krb.navigasi.petakebunrayabogor"
        minSdkVersion 10
        targetSdkVersion 23
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
    productFlavors {
    }
}
```

It runs fine in android 5.0 but how can i solve these warnings? I hope there's someone can help me to fix my code above. Any help will be greatly appreciated.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Apache Http module has been removed in the latest versions. So you have to choose another option like OkHttp, Volley something like this.

Comment: @Michael Julyus Christopher M.: decrease values for compileSdkVersion, buildToolsVersion and targetSdkVersion n see it shd work coz they are deprecated in API 23.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just initialize this,and sync

```
compile 'org.jbundle.util.osgi.wrapped:org.jbundle.util.osgi.wrapped.org.apache.http.cli‌​ent:4.1.2'
```

Comment: Have you run it in android 6.0? Is it works fine in android 6.0?

Comment: I have tried your edited code, but is shows me deprecated warning. But if i use your previous answer like this `compile 'org.jbundle.util.osgi.wrapped:org.jbundle.util.osgi.wrapped.org.apache.http.client:4.1.2'` The deprecated warnings will disappear. So , Which one is true? Your previous answer or your edited answer?

Comment: Yeah, but i haven't try it in android 6.0. I have try it in android 5.0 and it works well. But I am still not sure to android 6.0, whether successful or not. Have you tried it directly on the android 6.0 device (not in emulator)?

Comment: Sorry, i can't try it because my device is android 5.0 and i can't try it using emulator because my laptop will lag if i run the emulator. Have you try it in android 6.0 ? Thanks anyway.

Comment: i said yes..it is working in 6.0...and you need to try it by yourself..and accept answer if it helped..

Answer (score 2):

As it's been already answered that mentioned classes has been deprecated, Android documentations suggest you to use [HttpURLConnection](http://developer.android.com/reference/java/net/HttpURLConnection.html) where you can handle network calls on your own make sure you write them off the main thread.

given bellow is an example how you can `POST` an entity using `HttpURLConnection`

```
            HttpURLConnection httpURLConnection = (HttpURLConnection)url.openConnection();
            httpURLConnection.setDoOutput(true);
            httpURLConnection.setRequestMethod("POST"); // hear you are telling that it is a POST request, which can be changed into "PUT", "GET", "DELETE" etc.
            httpURLConnection.setRequestProperty("Content-Type", "application/json"); // here you are setting the `Content-Type` for the data you are sending which is `application/json` 
            httpURLConnection.connect();
```

and when you are posting some data to the instance of the `HttpURLConnection` you can do it like this...

```
            JsonObject jsonObject = new JsonObject();
            jsonObject.addProperty("para_1", "arg_1");
            jsonObject.addProperty("para_2", "arg_2");

            DataOutputStream wr = new DataOutputStream(httpURLConnection.getOutputStream());
            wr.writeBytes(jsonObject.toString());
            wr.flush();
            wr.close();
```

As this class comes in bundled with android framework no need add any library, but I would suggest you to use something like [OkHTTP](http://square.github.io/okhttp/),

this will take care of network calls of other thread and given example shows how you can post

```
public static final MediaType JSON
    = MediaType.parse("application/json; charset=utf-8");

OkHttpClient client = new OkHttpClient();

String post(String url, String json) throws IOException {
  RequestBody body = RequestBody.create(JSON, json);
  Request request = new Request.Builder()
      .url(url)
      .post(body)
      .build();
  Response response = client.newCall(request).execute();
  return response.body().string();
}
```

This example is calling the network call on the main thread you rather want to make enqueue like this

```
    okHttpClient.newCall(request).enqueue(new Callback() {
        @Override
        public void onFailure(Call call, IOException e) {

        }

        @Override
        public void onResponse(Call call, Response response) throws IOException {

        }
    });
```

Comment: Can you help me to fix my code that i posted above? Sorry, i'm new in android :(

Comment: you may use the code in the answer, both snippet would work with minor changes, if you still face any issue pass me the URL from which you are getting the response that I may tell you what to do